# How to install Lua libraries on separate folder

Tags: lua, luasocket

Hello i would like to change folder that luasocket is installing to how can i do that ? My plan is at the end i want to export my lua file as exe and use it to run my server. I want to put luasocket inside Project file so other windows computer wont have problems (I am using Windows computer too). Thanks for helping.

my code

Main.lua

> lpackage.path = package.path..';./libs/lua/?.lua' 
>   package.cpath = package.cpath..';./libs/socket/?.dll;'

This is my Project tree
Project 
-libs 
--lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you keep the name of the luasocket DLL the same (which is usually, `core.dll`),  you need to use `./libs/?.dll` instead of `./libs/socket/?.dll`, as the question mark will be replaced with `socket/core` when `socket.core` module is required from `socket.lua`. You'll need to put `core.dll` in `libs/socket` folder.

You will also need to have `lua.dll` present (as the core.dll is usually compiled against it) or use a [proxy dll](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaProxyDllFour) if your executable statically compiles lua interpreter.